# GZIP compression rate is less in JDK1.6.40 than older versions

Tags: java, tomcat7

We are using Tomcat 7.0.57 & JDK1.6.0.35. In server.xml we have put entries as follows:

```
<Connector compressableMimeType="text/html,text/xml,text/json,text/javascript,text/css,text/plain,application/json,application/javascript" compression="on" compressionMinSize="2048" connectionTimeout="200000" noCompressionUserAgents="gozilla, traviata" port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" redirectPort="8443"/>
```

The compression rate is almost double compared to the earlier version which was JDK 1.6.0.24 & same tomcat version.

Can anybody explain this?

Comment: Does it make a difference when you explicitly set the compression level, e.g `compression="6"`?

Comment: Yes but it does not make any difference

Comment: finally understand that it Jstl written by us is not getting compressed. If we do not call it from the page its compressing equally